# vegas pro - set relative path to used pictures in a project

Tags: path, sony-vegas

Vegas Pro - all versions - one thing makes me crazy

changing the location of a project folder - there is always a message - the media is offline (i.e. my pictures used for a slide show, for example).

Yes, I can re-set the new path, but I change the organization of my folders
very often and it is not suitable the set the new location each time.

plus - if I copy-paste a project on another computer - additional problems with all paths.

It is normal to have a relative path to media inside a project, so if a main folder is moved, the images inside have path unchanged.

Is there a way to tell the application to keep my files on relative path inside a project.

Comment: @music2myear - why you deleted my question - WHY DEVELOPERS MAKES SO STUPID SOLUTIONS?

Comment: We cannot answer "why" questions because we didn't write this program. We also don't accept posts with more than one question. I did you a favor by removing the part of your post that was going to get it closed as too broad, opinion based, and unprofessional. Please read the Help section to familiarize yourself more with what Superuser is about.